# file_get_content issues

Tags: php, windows, file-get-contents

I am having issues with `file_get_content` when it is place recursively.

My PHP works perfectly on a Linux machine, but on windows I receive a "Server Error" (Chrome) or 500 Internal error (IE).

Also if I do a single `file_get_contents` command it works perfectly on Windows, the issue is when it is recursive.

Comment: Please show what you mean by placing  file_get_content recursively

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I won't copy paste the program as it is called from different functions but basically:  

foreach ($website as $websites) 
{ 
$source = file_get_contents($url); 
}  
Like I mentioned, it works perfectly in linux. It works perfectly in Windows if I comment the foreach loop but fails with the foreach loop.

Comment: Check your logs. A 500 internal error means there was a server-side error, could be a lot of things. Find the specific error you are hitting.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on looking into the log file! The issue was a timeout issue. I guess because I was calling it so many times, it did not know it was a new website.

I guess the default timeout on apache for a linux install is longer? Not sure.. I fixed it with set_time_limit() though!